# Initialization of static class variable inside the main

Tags: c++, static, initialization

I have a static variable in the class.
I am Initializing that in the global scope, its works fine.

But
When I try to Initialize in the main linker throws an error.
Why it so.

```
class Myclass{

    static int iCount;
} ;

int main(){

  int Myclass::iCount=1;

}
```

And In global scope why I have to specify the variable type
like

```
int Myclass::iCount=1;
```

As In my class I am definig iCount as integer type why not.

```
   Myclass::iCount =1 ; in //Global scope
```

Comment: @goreSplatter: `Myclass::iCount` is not public, it would fail.

Comment: @goreSplatter: What @peoro said, but also even if it were public, that would be an *assignment* not and *initialisation*

Comment: @peoro : *initialization* of private static data members don't fail!! other accesses, like *assignment*, will fail.

Comment: @Nawaz: you didn't read the comment I was answering to. It was suggested to put a `Myclass::iCount=1;` in `main`.

Comment: @peoro: you were talking about assignment or initialization?

Comment: @Nawaz: assignment, since initilaziation can't be done in a function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The section $9.4.2/7 from the C++ Standard says,

> Static data members are **initialized**
>   and destroyed **exactly like non-local**
>   objects (3.6.2, 3.6.3).

Note the phrases **"initialized"** and **"exactly like non-local objects"**. Hope that explains why you cannot do that.

In fact, static members are more like global objects accessed through `Myclass::iCount`. So, you've to initialize them at global scope (the same scope at which class is defined), like this:

```
class Myclass{

    static int iCount;
} ;
int Myclass::iCount=1;

int main(){
  /*** use Myclass::iCount here ****/
}
```

Similar topic:

[How do static member variables affect object size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640989/how-do-static-member-variables-affect-object-size/4640999#4640999)

Answer (score 3):

Because C++ syntax doesn't allow this. You need to instantiate your static variable outside of the scope of some function.

Besides you forget a semicolon `;` after your class ending bracket.

Answer (score 3):

this is the correct C++. Outside of a function, in a cpp file. the initialisation is done at the beginning/launching of the executable. ( even before calling main() );

```
//main.h

class Myclass{

    static int iCount;
}; // and don't forget this ";" after a class declaration


//main.cpp

int Myclass::iCount=1;

int main(){



}
```

Answer (score 2):

From C++ standard (§8.5/10):

`An initializer for a static member is in the scope of the member’s class.`

class `Myclass` has global scope and you tried to initialize its static member in the narrower scope - of the function `main`.

Answer (score 1):

The static initialisation occurs *before* main is called by the run-time initialisation.

Placing it within a function is not allowed because that is where *locally scoped* objects are declared.  It would be confusing and ambiguous to allow that.